# Is there a way to handle push notification if the device gets locked and the app was in foreground?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I don't know if it is possible or if I am missing anything very simple here.

Well, my use case is pretty much simple - I have an app which I am playing around with and then suddenly I click on the Power button of my iPhone and the device gets locked. At this point of time say, I receive a remote notification for my app which I was using.

Now if I unlock the device, I see my app in the foreground. Is there a way to handle the remote notification that I received as soon as I unlocked my device? Otherwise, do I mandatorily need to go to the notification center (even though my app is in the foreground after getting unlocked) and click on the received notification to handle it?

Thanks!!

Comment: you can't control Remote Push notification from you home button press. As a beginner such type of questions are normal.

Comment: The push either goes to the app or it goes to the notification center, if the app doesn't receive it because the device is locked and the notification goes to the notification center then the app can't retrieve it (there's no way an app can query the notification center to see what notifications are there).